# Database context change is throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework

I am totally new to Entity Framework and trying to build something on my own based on the Rick Anderson Tutorial from the [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net) site. I have created a model named **HostelName** and a DBContext named **HostelNameDBContext**. My solution name is - **LaundryManagementSystem**.

Here's my model code:

```
public class HostelName
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class HostelNameDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<HostelName> HostelNames { get; set; }
}
```

Probably because adding the `[Required]` attribute after creating the model class, I'm facing the following exception:

`InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'HostelNameDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)`

I tried the following:

In my Visual Studio 2012, Go to TOOLS->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console, then type `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName LaundryManagementSystem.Models.HostelName` in the console, then build and run the solution again, but I'm still getting the above exception.

Note that this is Entity Framework, Code First approach.

Can someone please point out where my problem is, what possibly am I missing and how to get around this?

Comment: Either enable automatic migrations or type `Update-Database`. Try searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling migrations you need to create migrations and then update the database.

To create migration in nuget console run `Add-Migration AddedRequiredToProperties`. This should create migration files.

Then run `Update-Database -Verbose` to apply the migration to the database. This will run the migration script on the database, changing the table structure.

Comment: Can I write anything after the text `Add-Migration`? My command that I just wrote was `Add-Migration Hostel-A`. I then ran the `Update-Database` command and now it's working perfectly. Is it okay? Please explain this stuff to me, I'm totally new to Entity Framework.

Comment: `AddRequiredProperties` is a migration name - it can be what you like. Why don't you start from reading a tutorial about EF migrations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx There is a myriad of articles about how to use migrations - you'll get a better explanations there.